# Cannot get setTimeout working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a simple css animation for webkit. A number of elements will slide in and then unfold.

My idea is to keep to have a single css animation and trigger it by adding the `slideIn` class with jquery.

```
.slideIn {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    clip: rect(0,125px,315px,0);
    }
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-700px); clip: rect(0,125px,315px,0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-700px); clip: rect(0,550px,315px,0); }
}
```

As I mentioned, there are more than one item on the page and I want them to slide in one by one. So I need to add the `slideIn` class one by one, with somtehing like:

```
var pref = "animated";
var animClass = "slideIn";
var eNumber = 5;
var interval = 10000;
animateMultiple(pref, eNumber, interval, animClass);

function animateMultiple(pref, eNumber, interval, animClass) {
    var i = 0;
    function addAnimClass() {
        i++;
        $('#' + pref + i).addClass(animClass);

        if(i < eNumber){
            setTimeout(addAnimClass(), interval);   
        }
    }
    addAnimClass ();
}
```

Yet, this ends in all the element sliding in alltogether.

Why does not the interval have any effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setTimeout(addAnimClass(), interval);
```

You are (immediately) **calling** `addAnimClass` and passing its return value (`undefined`) to `setTimeout`.

Remove the `()`.

Comment: Right! Meantime the solution I came up with was to call it in a function: "setTimeout(function() {addAnimClass();}, interval);". I know this way I can prevent "immediate" execution, but I do not know why.